# Partial vlookup between two columns and two different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Currently, I am working with multiple sheets in excel. One of my sheets is my master sheet from the DATABASE however, the sheets are data entered manually by some users, like the name and DOB. This means that they will make typos, insert commas or white spaces. I need to do a Vlookup formula or any formula where I will do a partial match for the name and DOB two columns between two sheets and get back a yes or no on my sheet.

so far I have tried this formula in one of my sheets and it works fine only if I look into one column and for an exact match.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(TRIM(A2),Mastersheet!$A:$A,0),"yes",),"no")
```

I have tried this formula for a partial match in both columns looking at my master sheet and the sheet.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&TRIM(A2)&"*",Mastersheet!$A:$A,0)*('Sheet'!"*"&TRIM(B2)&"*"='Mastersheet'!$B:$B,0),"yes",),"no")
```

Sheet1

```
name              DOB                 ismatch yes or no to mastersheet?
Morano Saljad    12/28/2001 
Moreno,Willis    12/28/2001 
Alice   jad      12/28/2001 
Alle   Sljad    12/28/2001
```

Master

```
name              DOB
    Julian Kaplan   11/25/1963
    Moreno Willis   12/28/1991 
    Alice   jad     07/28/1993 
    Alle   Sljad    12/25/1965  
    John   jad      07/28/1993 
    Alle   Wu       12/25/1965
   Alle   Sljad     12/28/2001
```

Comment: What type of data are the users entering on the sheets? Usually on this kind of situation, I prefer to limit the data entering, instead of trying to adapt my formulas for possible errors of the user. You can use [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) to restrict the type of data the user will supply.

Comment: They are entering name and DOB, this will be in sheet1 but the master sheet from the database is the other sheet that data will be comparing data with.

Comment: What you can do is a Data Validation on the names: On the Settings, in the Allow box, choose List. Refer to the range in the Master sheet, with the names, so the user will only enter a name on the Master Name, so you don't need to worry about typos.